Implementing Cube In and Cube Out Effect with Framer Motion in React
I'm working on a React project where I want to implement a cube in and cube out effect on a component transition. Currently, I have a Person component displayed from a list of people.
Each Person component has two buttons: "Swipe Left" and "Swipe Right". When either button is clicked, the next person in the list should be displayed with the specified cube transition effect.
I have managed to create a basic swipe left and swipe right transition using Framer Motion. However, I'm struggling to implement a more complex cube in and cube out effect as the index changes. I'm a complete beginner with Framer Motion, and my current implementation only uses opacity for transitions.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
"use client";

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Person from './person';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

const People = () => {

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const people = [];

    const handleNext = (direction) => {
        setIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + direction + people.length) % people.length);
    };

    return (
        <div className="pt-3">
            <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
                <motion.div
                    key={index}
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                >
                    <Person
                        key={people[index]._id}
                        person={people[index]}
                        handleSwipeRight={() => handleNext(1)}
                        handleSwipeLeft={() => handleNext(-1)}
                    />
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
    );
}

export default People;

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples to help me implement this effect. Thank you!
